# Cannot reach static files in Django 1.10

Tags: python, django, django-1.10

I am not getting any static files to show up in Django.

The repo is located at `git@bitbucket.org:codyc54321/bookwormbud.git`.

In settings.py I have

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I have a static folder in the root directory

I cannot reach any static files. The file in question right now is http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/bookshelf_background.jpg

The load failing is in `static/main.css`:

```
html {
    background-image:url('/static/images/bookshelf_background.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100%;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

I am using Django 1.10.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost, we can't have access to the url.

Comment: I updated the question to be clearer